# Warning about obtaining lock from other thread when accessing text field

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, cocoa-touch, uitextfield

I have a `UITextField` named `_passwordTextField`, where I'm hiding the input:

```
[_passwordTextField  setSecureTextEntry:YES];
```

every time I access the field's text with `passwordTextField.text`, I see this warning:

> void _WebThreadLockFromAnyThread(bool), 0x9077460: Obtaining the web lock from a thread other than the main thread or the web thread. UIKit should not be called from a secondary thread.

How do I remove this warning?

Comment: yes, all code called in main thread, and only SecureTextEntry UITextField gives this waring, normally for UITextField .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has nothing to do with `UITextField`. iOS `UIKit` requires any direct manipulation to UI to be done on main thread & not from background thread.

If you are doing this, your app will be unstable and in some situations might even crash. So as **a rule do not update UIKit elements from background thread.** Please inspect your code.

If you're using iOS >= 4, you can use [GCD](http://www.raywenderlich.com/4295/multithreading-and-grand-central-dispatch-on-ios-for-beginners-tutorial) do this instead:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [self doSomething:1 b:2 c:3 d:4 e:5]; //changes UI method
});
```

**UPDATE:** please check your code again. when dealing with threading issues, its not which line this warning occurs you need to observe but you need to see in its entirety. See if the entire method is getting called from main thread or background thread..

Comment: **[body setObject:_nameTextField.text forKey:@"username"]; // <- no waring here
    [body setObject:_passwordTextField.text forKey:@"password"];  // <- waring**, it looks only shows waring for SecureTextEntry UITextField.

Comment: please check your code again. when dealing with threading issues, its not which line this warning occurs you need to observe but you need to see in its entirety. See if the entire method is getting called from main thread or background thread