# Obtaining the web lock from a thread other than the main thread or the web thread. UIKit should not be called from a secondary thread

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I am getting an error

```
Obtaining the web lock from a thread other than the main thread or the web thread. UIKit should not be called from a secondary thread
```

for the code `NSString *tokenString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"username=%@&password=%@",[[userName.text lowercaseString] MD5],[password.text MD5]];`

I am using class file for for MD5. i got it from [MD5](http://iosdevelopertips.com/core-services/create-md5-hash-from-nsstring-nsdata-or-file.html)

This md5 causing the thread lock how can I remove this warning

Answer (score 2):

This happens when you call UIKit from secondary thread...

To solve this try the following

```
dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

//Call the function from here

});
```

or

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(yourmethod:)withObject:obj waitUntilDone:YES]
```

Answer (score 1):

To avoid crash use this function to call the method on main thread

Hope, this will be a solution for your issue.

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(doneButtonAction) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Obtaining the web lock from a thread other than the main thread or the web thread. UIKit should not be called from a secondary thread
```

The fix is conceptually simple; don't update the UI from your secondary  thread.update the UI from your main  thread by calling `performSelectorOnMainThread` method

Comment: i made the code like this  `__block NSString *tokenString;
                dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                
               tokenString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"username=%@&password=%@",[[userName.text lowercaseString] MD5],[password.text MD5]];
                });
` still its not working.

Comment: this code is not related to UI update there is other where you update UI.

Comment: I am taking text from the secure type text field is that causing problem ?

Comment: THe problem is with userName.text and password.text, extract uitextfields' text in the main thread if you are performing it in background queue or thread.

Answer (score 0):

A similar question has been already answered [here is the link to it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14207483/warning-about-obtaining-lock-from-other-thread-when-accessing-text-field?rq=1)
just use

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{      });
```

while obtaining the password and the username,

hope this solves your problem